# Heroku Server Timeout for Shopify App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, shopify, shopify-app

I have a Shopify App on a Heroku Server. One of the calls I make to that app is a POST where I send a Collection, an Array of Products and an Array of Customers. From there I make multiple API Calls to the Shopify Admin to create all those things. This is currently working great if there is just a few products and customers to create. Heroku, however, has a 30-second timeout limit. This cannot be changed. The only way around it is to send a "Heartbeat" and then you get an additional 55 seconds. I have not figured out how to send a "Heartbeat" back and continue on. I tried Returning a Status 100 but that didn't work. Other than splitting this into multiple calls. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're architecting your App poorly. If you make a POST to your App, organize the incoming data, send it to a background job to get processed, and then return a 200 OK back to your App if you used XHR, or splash up a page in your App saying "Thanks, we're working on things"...

That way you keep your merchant client informed, things work fine, and you have no chance of blowing out on a 30 second timeout.

Comment: I guess that is what I need to figure out. Sending the data to a background job. Not a big deal. Just never done it in Ruby before.

Comment: Background job processing is pretty easy with Resque, DelayedJob and other gems. App architecture is not dependent on scripting language so how you choose to build an app is often a lot more important than the scripting language you choose to write it in.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what the ruby answer would be but Heroku's article on this is [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout) and indicates that you just need to send few bytes after each operation to get an additional 55s per write operation.

I presume ruby has some way to get access to the response stream so even a space character sent down may do the trick -- that way you can send a bunch of spaces and then a final JSON response.